# list variables by group as character string in data frame column

Tags: r

I have a data set with the following structure:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
session = seq(1,10,1))

df2 <- data.frame(
session = rep(1:10, each=4),
sample = seq(1,40,1))
```

What I need returned is a df1 with the following structure:

```
session | sample.list
 1      |    1,2,3,4
 2      |    5,6,7,8
 3      |    9,10,11,12
...
```

Basically its lists all the samples taken within a given session.

Thanks for any pointers or solutions to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base R

```
aggregate(sample ~ session, df2, toString)
```

Or (depends on the type of the desired result)

```
aggregate(sample ~ session, df2, list)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, list(sample.list=toString(sample)), session]
```

Or if you need the column as list

```
setDT(df2)[, list(sample.list=list(sample)), session]
```

#### Update

For listing unique "samples"

```
 aggregate(sample ~ session, df2, function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```

Or

```
 setDT(df2)[, list(toString(unique(sample))), session]
```

Comment: Concise and best solution!

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Thanks, but your solution can be made concise using `ddply` or  dplyr

Comment: I let you adding the plyr solution!

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I am not adding it, you can modify your solution.

Comment: one extension to the original question - is there a way to just list unique samples in the column sample.list? I have some sessions where the same samples were repeated.